# R C5.0 Undefined columns selected when using a formula stored in a variable

Tags: r, decision-tree, r-package

I'm using the [C50 R Package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/C50/C50.pdf) for predicting with decision trees.

I have the following code:

```
library("partykit")
library("C50")

//Creates a sample data frame
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
               var1 = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'),
               var2 = c(1, 1, 0, 0, 1))

//This is the variable I want to predict
variable <- "ID"

//First I convert the column to factor
data[, variable] <- factor(data[, variable])

//Then I create the formula
formula <- as.formula(paste(variable, " ~ ."))

//And finally I fit the model with the formula
model <- C5.0(formula, data=data, trials=10)
```

Until this point everything is ok, the problem comes here, when I try to plot the tree:

```
png(filename = paste("test.png"), width = 800, height = 60)
plot(model) //This line throws the error: Error in `[.data.frame`(mf, rsp) : undefined columns selected
dev.off()
```

But if I change the line:

```
model <- C5.0(formula, data=data, trials=10)
```

To:

```
model <- C5.0(ID ~ ., data=data, trials=10)
```

Everything is ok.

After doing a bit of debugging I have this adicional info:

Inside C5.0 function there is this code:

```
call <- match.call()
```

If I look inside `call` this is what I get:

```
C5.0.formula(formula = formula, data = data, trials = 10)
```

But if the call to C5.0 is:

```
model <- C5.0(ID ~ ., data=data, trials=10)
```

Then the `call` object is this:

```
C5.0.formula(formula = ID ~ ., data = data, trials = 10)
```

This may seem normal, but debugging the `plot()` function I've seen that in some point the function `as.party(x, trial = trial)` is called, where `x` is the C5.0 object. Inside `as.party()` function there is another call, the `model.frame(obj)` call, where `obj` is the `C5.0` object, and here is the problem. Inside the `model.frame()` function I found this line:

```
rsp <- strsplit(paste(formula$call[2]), " ")[[1]][1]
```

Remember? The error had a reference to that `rsp` variable. And the problem is that `formula$call` has 2 different values. If I make the first call to C.5 like this one:

```
model <- C5.0(ID ~ ., data=data, trials=10)
```

Everything is ok as `formula$call` contains `C5.0.formula(formula = ID ~ ., data = data, trials = 10)` and `rap` is `ID` so the next call to:

```
tmp <- mf[rsp]
```

Is executed without problems (mf is the initial data frame).

But with the call:

```
C5.0.formula(formula = formula, data = data, trials = 10)
```

The `formula$call` object contains:

```
C5.0.formula(formula = formula, data = data, trials = 10)
```

And `rsp` is `"formula"` so the line:

```
tmp <- mf[rsp]
```

Fails as there is no `"formula"` column in the data frame.

Is this the expected behavior? If it is, there is no way I can call C5.0 with a formula stored in a variable?

I need to do the call that way in order to test the algorithm with many different formulas.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately it is a bug. See [issue 8](https://github.com/topepo/C5.0/issues/8) on github. Looks like Max Kuhn (developer of C50) hasn't had the time to look into it, since the bug report is from August. You might want to attach your issue there as well. That might bring it back to the attention of the developer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll do it.